# How to make a image texture sequence longer?

Tags: texturing

[image: Image Sequence Settings]I have 3 images in blender for a texture image sequence. How do I make these last longer than one second? I tried changing the frames and using the shader editor, but I'm not sure.
Anyone know?

Comment: Are you talking about the Video Sequencer? You need to grab the right hand bracket of the strip and drag

Comment: @moonboots its for a texture in the shader editor.

Comment: I added a image if that helps.

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen, with your current setup the 3 images will be played in a loop, do you want each image to be played for 1 second?

Comment: Ill try your idea. I want it each image to be played for several seconds.

Comment: Ok so it should work  ;)

Comment: also would I use your same method below for  this process if I wanted the face to be changed after the guy gets punched?

Comment: do you mean that you use image to make the face expressions? In that case use the same method. If this is a completely different question please ask as a new question   ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have image 1, 2 and 3 played for one second each, at frame 1 in the *Timeline* you need to set *Frames* at 1, *Start Frame* at 1, *Offset* at 0, keyframe the *Offset*:

[image]

At frame 24 in the *Timeline* you need to set the *Offset* at 1 and keyframe:

[image]

At frame 48 in the *Timeline* you need to set the *Offset* at 2 and keyframe:

[image]

To make image 2 happen at frame 24 (and not between frame 1 and 24) and image 3 happen at frame 48, select all the keyframes and press <kbd>T</kbd> (*Interpolation*) > *Constant*:

[image]

After frame 72 the image 3 will play indefinitely. To come back to image 1 and repeat the loop, duplicate the first keyframe, put it at frame 72, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Make Cyclic*:

[image]